# Powershell get member attribute return Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've tried below script on powershell, but the value come out in csv are Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity “gov2” | select SamAccountName | Export-csv -path "C:\New folder\gov2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Either remove the curly quotes around `“gov2”` or replace them with straight ones `'gov2'`

Answer (score 0):

Thank You [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) for your suggestion in comment to help other community member.

Executed this command and it is working for me

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity 'gov2' | select SamAccountName | Export-csv -path "C:\Sample\gov2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

Output--

[image]